# How to advance to next node in MIPS 32?

Tags: mips, mips32

I have this function:

```
makenode:
    li $v0, 9                 #allocate memory
    li $a0, 8                 #8 bytes
    syscall                   #$v0 <---- address
    move $s1, $v0             #$s1 = address of first node
    sw $t4, 0($s1)            #$t4 is a string
    sw $s2, 4($s1)            #copy address of 2nd node
                              #into first node
```

Can it be done like this? That 4($s1) points to $2 even though it hasn't been created yet?

and since this is a function (which will be called again), how do I make it that it will work on the next run? Do I increment $s1 so it now represents $s2?

Comment: What is this `$2` that you speak of and why do you think it hasn't been created yet?

Comment: it is supposed to be the next node, mym question was can I point to that address before creating the actual node? since the next call to the function will create the actual node

Comment: As long as the register contains the address of the new node you are free to pass it around, just know that obviously if you attempt to use the address before it is valid you may `segfault`

Comment: also is it possible that I have a pointer point to the next node? so say I have $s1, but i want it to point to $s2, and the next call of the function will create a node at this location (now $s1). So this function call can work in a lopp.